# Enqueue script with version number not working

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, cache, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to enqueue a script for a custom plugin and I want to include a version number for cache busting. However, the ?ver= query is not being appended to the script name in the html and therefore cache busting is failing.

The php code:

```
wp_enqueue_script('bundle', plugins_url('dist/client.js', __FILE__), array(), '20190520430', true);
```

And the html tag that is being produced (with identifiable info removed):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://site.url/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/dist/client.js"></script>
```

Any help or explanation is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What's your `wp_register_script()` for that script?

Comment: Where am I supposed to put it? I can have `wp_register_script('bundle', plugins_url('dist/client.js', __FILE__), array(), '20190520430', true); wp_enqueue_script('bundle');` and it results in the same thing?

Comment: You can enqueue and register at the same time with `wp_enqueue_script`, don't worry about not calling `wp_register_script`. Ryan, is this happening with other scripts too? Or just this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't strictly need `wp_register_script()` but it is considered a best practice to use it as it allows other developers to programmatically work with the order and list of scripts being included.

Regarding your issue, your code looks correct. Be sure to call it inside the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action (but I don't think that's influencing the behavior you are seeing).

If I had to guess, and I kind of do, I would guess that there is some other plugin or system configuration that is stripping the query string as part of a caching mechanism. The thought is that query string parameters, if they are present, can keep some proxy servers, and possibly browsers, from caching the resource. There are even some plugins such as [Ratify](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ratify/) and possibly [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) that will strip query string parameters from resources for you, intentionally. The way to test if another plugin is interfering is by disabling them and seeing if anything changes.

If you are using a caching server or CDN, they *may* also be stripping the query string (but seems unlikely). Cloudflare offers a maintenance mode that allows you to briefly disable the CDN while you test things.

HTH and please let me know how you get on.

Comment: It turned out to be a setting in the KLEO child theme that turned off query strings. Thanks for helping!